# Java operators, explanation

Tags: java, operators

I know there are several question about the x++ operation, I know the difference between ++x and x++. But now I have to solve this:

```
int x = 5;
x += x++ * x++ * x++;
```

Well I know that this shouldn't be too difficult, but still, I need an explanation how this calculatino is done, step by step, I don't get it by myself..

Comment: @user3145373ツ Yes, it compiles and results in 215 :)

Comment: Have you run the code? I'd look at running a few permutations of this until you can figure out what's going on (`0 += x++ * x++ * x++`, `x += x++ * x++`, `x += (x++ * x++) * x++`, etc.), or consult the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/).

Comment: You should **never ever** write code like this, and **never ever** need to read it.  So you could argue that knowing the solution is ... pointless.

Comment: @StephenC yeah, true.. but I wanna know it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
int x = 5;
int originalX = x;
int a = x++;
int b = x++;
int c = x++;
x = originalX + a * b * c;
System.out.println("x = " + x); //215
```

Comment: +1. This is the best answer here.. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I agree

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html <- explains why this order.

Comment: Wow, short and simple answer. I didn't try to cut it in small pieces, don't know why I didn't came up with that.

Answer (score 2):

```
x += x++ * x++ * x++;
```

can be written as:

```
x = x+ x++ * x++ * x++;
```

how will it be evaluated?
`x= 5+(5 * 6 * 7)` because you are using postfix. So, the incremented value of `x` will be visible from the second time it is used.

```
So, final output = 5+ (5*6*7) == 215
```

Answer (score 1):

x++ would mean read the value and use it in the place which is referenced and then increment it.

So in your question:-

```
int x = 5;
x  = 5 +   5   * 6   *  7
x += x++ * x++ * x++;
x = 215
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 5;
x += x++ * x++ * x++;
```

First, set some brackets to better see the calculation sequence:

```
x += ((x++ * x++) * x++);
```

Then, replace the first occurance of x with it's value, calculate, and continiue replacing with updated values:

```
5 += ((x++ * x++) * x++);

5 += ((5 * x++) * x++);

5 += ((5 * 6) * x++);

5 += ((5 * 6) * 7);

5 += 210;
```

and now, it's plain math...

Result should be: 215

And my compile gives me: 215

So I *think* my explanation is correct. But i'm not 100% sure...